# Usage Shellscript export variable in SQL query

Tags: shell, sqlplus

Can we use shell script export variable in SQL query ?

Example below:

```
export name=Georgia;
Connect sqlplus through linux server 

$Oraclepath/sqlplus -s username/password@schemaname

Select * from employee where first_name='$name';
```

Can some one help me on this ?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do something like this from the command line:

```
$Oraclepath/sqlplus -s username/password <<eof
select * from employee where first_name='$name';
eof
```

Everything between the opening `<<eof` and the closing `eof` is called a heredoc.

Comment: I've edited your answer because the formatting was hiding a good part of your answer (I think the `<eof` followed at the next line by the citation's `>` was parsed as an XML tag and its content hidden) and I've used the opportunity to remove the pleasantries from the end of your answer (see [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts) for a rationale) but I think  this is a great first answer anyway, keep it up ! Note that you can rollback my edit or edit over it if you wish.

Comment: thank you Aaron, I was struggling with the markdown

Comment: You're welcome! I promise it's usually not that troublesome!